# View pager load off screen causing Fragement to load the wrong data

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-youtube-api

I have a view pager with `offScreenLimit set to 5.` inside each page there is a youtube player fragment. It works well however, it loads the video of the 5th page rather than the first.

If i am on page 1 it quickly loads page 1,2,3,4, then stays on 5. I need it to only load the video associated with the page i am on.

I think the problem is that I am creating the fragement wrong. every view on the pager is loading  the correct data, except for the player fragment

**Inside my view pager fragment**

*I am calling the method below from onCreateView()*

```
public void loadPlayer(final String trailerUrl) {

    YouTubePlayerSupportFragment youTubePlayerFragment = YouTubePlayerSupportFragment
            .newInstance();
    getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.youtube_fragment, youTubePlayerFragment).commit();

        youTubePlayerFragment.initialize(Utils.DEVELOPER_KEY,
                new OnInitializedListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onInitializationSuccess(Provider arg0,
                            YouTubePlayer player, boolean wasRestored) {
                        if (!wasRestored) {
                            player.cueVideo(trailerUrl);
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onInitializationFailure(Provider arg0,
                            YouTubeInitializationResult errorReason) {
                    }

                });

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem and was able to solve it by using `setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser)` method in fragments. You should override this method and use it as indicator that your fragment is currently visible (if `isVisibleToUser` is true). So, if this method is invoked with `isVisibleToUser==true`, then you can invoke `loadPlayer` method.